# How to select from User Defined Table Type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Select * from sys.table_types where user_type_id = TYPE_ID(N'dbo.udt_test');
```

The above query returns me data but when I try to query the data within, it says `dbo.udt_test` not exists?

```
Select * from dbo.udt_test
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131086.aspx

Referred to the above link, there should be no problem with the select query to display data. May I know if I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `dbo.udt_test` **is a Table Type, not a Table instance**.

The link in your question shows how a `User Defined Type` is defined and is used as data type for column.

you seem to have created a new table type.

You can create table variable of type `dbo.udt_test` and use that table to insert/update/delete/select data from it.

In the link, you have this code..

`INSERT INTO dbo.Points (PointValue) VALUES (CONVERT(Point, '3,4'));`

'Point' is a type here. You cannot do `select Point from Sometable` same as in the case of `Select VARCHAR from Sometable`

In the same way, you cannot have `SELECT * FROM TABLETYPE`